# How do I get the ID of an object after persisting it in PyMongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a PyMongo newbie question: If `collection` is a PyMongo [Collection](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.7%2B/api/pymongo/collection.html) and I use it to save an object with

```
obj = {'foo': 'bar'}
collection.insert(obj)
```

then MongoDB automatically generates an `_id` field for `obj`; once can confirm this with

```
print obj
```

which yields something like

```
{'foo': 'bar', '_id': ObjectId('4c2fea1d289c7d837e000000')}
```

My question is: How do I get that `_id` back out in such a way that I can use it?

For instance, if I want to delete `obj` from the database, I would think that I would want to do something like

```
collection.remove(obj['_id'])
```

but when I try this I get the message

```
TypeError: 'ObjectId' object is unsubscriptable.
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

insert returns the _id of the inserted document.

and remove will remove based on _id, so try something like:

```
doc_id = db.test.insert({"foo": 1})
db.test.remove(doc_id)
```

Answer (score 12):

You just need to pass `remove` a dict, just like you did `insert`.  So, to remove a document based on its `_id` value, do something like:

```
collection.remove({'_id': ObjectId('4c2fea1d289c7d837e000000')})
```

Comment: Ah, I see. What is the purpose of the ObjectId wrapper, anyway?

Comment: It's a special type.  It's more compact than a string and contains a timestamp for when it was created, which you can access with generation_time (http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.7%2B/api/pymongo/objectid.html)

Comment: `ObjectId` can be imported with `from pymongo.objectid import ObjectId` for those looking for it.

Comment: @T.Stone: Thank you for that. It's been driving me insane.

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass `obj`.

Answer (score -1):

for removing a object from document you have to mention condition 
As you can specify "_id" for a document ........

```
_id = db.test.insert({"foo": "test"})
db.test.remove({"_id":_id})
```